# An instance of different structures as a argument for a function

Tags: rust

There're some structures:

```
struct St1 {
  ..
}

impl St1 {
  pub fn new() -> St1 {
    //.......
  }
}

struct St2 {
  ..
}

impl St2 {
  pub fn new() -> St2 {
    //.......
  }
}

//and so on
```

There aren't related to each other in terms of inheritance, they don't implement any common interface. I want to create a function which accepts an **instance** of any of these structs:

```
fn my_func(???) { .... }
```

How do I do that? I was thinking about creating a enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
  St1::new(), //error!
  St2::new()  //error!
}

// and then
fn my_func(en: MyEnum) { .... }
```

but as you can see it doesn't work. Your ideas?

Note that the structs S1, S2, S3 are from a library so I can't change them.

Answer (score 3):

To create an enum, you'd rather do:

```
enum MyEnum {
   MySt1(St1),
   MySt2(St2)
}
```

That is, it has two variants, each carrying data of the respective type.

Another way to do this if you don't care about *which* variant you have is to define your own trait and implement it for both:

```
trait Stuff { }
impl Stuff for St1 { }
impl Stuff for St2 { }

fn my_func<T: Stuff>(en: T) { ... }
```

This has the advantage of not having to duplicate handling and adding an enum. This is called an "extension implementation", since you're *extending* the type with a trait it didn't used to implement.

Comment: what does `St1(St1),` mean syntax-wise?

Comment: in the 2nd case `impl Stuff for St1 { }` has to be empty as well as the trait itself, right?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: the trait and the `impl` have to implement *all* the functions/methods you wish to use within `my_func`, because any function not part of the trait cannot be called on the `en` argument (since statically the only known thing is that `en` is of a type that implements `Stuff`).

Comment: in the 2nd case impl Stuff for St1 { } has to be empty as well as the trait itself, right?

Comment: Will `St1(St1)` really work? AFAIK enums now put their variants to type namespace to, so there should be a name conflict.